# Jquery animate on mousing over the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have the following snippet of code:

```
<div class="bubblewrap">
    <div class="bubblebar">
        This is the popup bar
    </div>
    <div class="bubble">
        This is a bubble<br/>
        See?
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(".bubblewrap").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find(".bubblebar").animate({top: 0px}, slow);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find(".bubblebar").animate({top: 12px}, slow);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8g52G/

I am trying to make it so on mouse over of any `.bubblewrap`, it moves the `.bubblebar` within.  However, it doesn't seem to trigger the event(tested a simple alert).  I must be doing it the wrong way, could someone help me?

Comment: To load jQuery library in a jsFiddle: At top left, under `Frameworks & Extensions`, change `No-Library (pure JS)` to `jQuery 1.8.3` (or whatever version you require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add jQuery in your fiddle, and didn't quote some of the values that should be passed as strings

```
$(".bubblewrap").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find(".bubblebar").animate({top: '0px'}, 'slow');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find(".bubblebar").animate({top: '12px'}, 'slow');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8g52G/1/)

as a sidenote you could also do

```
$(".bubblewrap").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
    $(this).find(".bubblebar").animate({top: e.type=='mouseenter'?0:12}, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: Single quotes, oh how the stupid have fallen!  Will tick in 11 minutes!

Comment: @JamesKorden - double quotes would have worked as well

Answer (score 1):

3 things :

1. jQuery isnt loaded in fiddle.
2. `12px` should be a string, now it is considered as a var name.
3. same thing for `slow`.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8g52G/2/